# Creating Uri for camera foto - Can't find file

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using the camera in my Android App and I want to save the full size foto, not just Bitmap. I implemented it following the documentation.

```
public class CameraUtil {

    public static Uri takePhotoIntent(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File photoFile = null;

        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile(activity);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", photoFile);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    photoURI);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent,
                    REQUEST_CAMERA);
            return photoURI;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static File createImageFile(Context context) throws IOException {
        String timeStamp =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                        Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir =
                context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        return image;
    }
}
```

I implemented it in my activity the following way:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Uri photoUri;

    // On button click open camera
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        photoUri = CameraUtil.takePhotoIntent(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            if (requestCode == CameraUtils.REQUEST_CAMERA)
            {
                File file = new File(photoUri.getPath());
                // This returns false
                Log.i("Files", "Exists file: " + file.exists());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GenericFileProvider:

```
public class GenericFileProvider extends FileProvider {}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    <application
        ...
        <provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but The file doesn't exist. I realized, that `Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", photoFile);` and then calling `photoUri.getPath();` returns another path than `photoFile.getPath();`. The first one is `/external_files/Android/data/<Package-Name>/files/Pictures/<Image-Name>.jpg` and the second one is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package-Name>/files/Pictures/<Image-Name>.jpg`.

I tried this: `Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);`. Here, the paths are the same, but I can't save the Image there, because it returns a `FileUriExposedException`.

So, how can I save the photo to a URI and then get the File with that URI?

Comment: Have a look at photoUri.toString() to begin with.

Comment: `File file = new File(photoUri.getPath())`. That will not work. Use `photoFile` instead. That was your file.

Comment: @blackapps But is there a way to get it from the Uri?

Comment: photoUri.getPath().replace("/external_files/", "/storage/emulated/0/");